# Foreign reference doesn't work with category system in database

Tags: mysql, database

I have a problem with adding constraint foreign key to my table.

Below is a code I setup in my base:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `basename`.`Category_News` (
  `Id_Category` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Id_Category_Parent` INT NULL,
  `Name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `Desc` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `Published` ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id_Category`),
  INDEX `fk_Category_Newsa_idx` (`Id_Category_Parent` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Category_News`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Id_Category_Parent`)
    REFERENCES `basename`.`Category_News` (`Id_Category`)
  ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I changed base engine from MyISAM to InnoDB but...

Can someone tell me, why when I insert new row for e.g. with atribute Id_Category_Parent = 8 there are no error even if category with this id not exists ?

Comment: you get an error when trying to create the table with the FK or after the table is created, at insert?

Comment: NoI didn't have any problems with creating table. And inserting new rows too even if Id_Category_Parent doesn't exist in base :/

Comment: can you add an example of insert statement that fails? Or an example of  insert statement that should fail due to the FK constraint?

Comment: [`foreign_key_checks`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks) must be disabled. (and please replace this hideous `ENUM('0','1')` with [`BOOLEAN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-type-overview.html#idm139990711466176) ;)

Comment: Ok, two first inserts on empty table:

INSERT INTO `basename`.`komentarze_newsa` (`Id_Category`, `Id_Category_Parent`, 'Name', 'Desc', 'Published')
VALUES (1, NULL, 'ex', 'ex', '0');

INSERT INTO `basename`.`komentarze_newsa` (`Id_Category`, `Id_Category_Parent`, 'Name', 'Desc', 'Published')
VALUES (2, 10, 'ex', 'ex', '0');

And I think that the second insert should give an error because category with Id = 10 not exist, is not inserted.

Comment: @Kuba, now it's clear: the insert statements are valid and second should trigger an error. You may want to check previous comment from RandomSeed.

Comment: @RandomSeed, please add an answer below with your comment that helped so that Kuba can close this item(?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Foreign key not working in MySQL: Why can I INSERT a value that's not in the foreign column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380057/foreign-key-not-working-in-mysql-why-can-i-insert-a-value-thats-not-in-the-for)

Answer (score 0):

Solution was really simple.

1. Change engine to InnoDB for your tables
2. Enable FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS in your database:

   SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;