# MySQL FORIEGN_KEY_CHECKS=1 by default, but not working

Tags: mysql

On MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.25, for Linux (x86_64), it seems that the default setting `@@GLOBAL.foreign_key_checks=1` does not work, because I tried to`INSERT` a row that contained values that are not present in the parent tables' keys and the `INSERT` was successful.

**Why do I have to `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1` even though `foreign_key_checks=1` is set by default?**

For example, I have a table that looks like the following:

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE score\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: score
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `score` (
  `student_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `event_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `score` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`,`student_id`),
  KEY `student_id` (`student_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_event_id` FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `grace_event` (`event_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_student_id` FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES `student` (`student_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

...I entered `mysql> INSERT INTO score (event_id,student_id,score) VALUES(9999,9999,0);` and got this...

`Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)`

So, trying to figure why the `INSERT` was successful when it should **not** have been, I read the following web pages...

- ['SET foreign_key_checks = 1' does not work again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28481743/set-foreign-key-checks-1-does-not-work-again)
- [Foreign key not working in MySQL: Why can I INSERT a value that's not in the foreign column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380057/foreign-key-not-working-in-mysql-why-can-i-insert-a-value-thats-not-in-the-for)

...but none of them seem to explain why/how the `INSERT` was successful (unfortunately).

I made sure all of the following were true for my 3 tables:

- Foreign keys must be `INT UNSIGNED`. Yes.
- Default storage engine must be `InnoDB`. Yes.
- Use `ON UPDATE CASCADE` for each foreign key declaration. Yes.
- phpmyadmin shows `foreign key checks` is set to `ON`. Yes.

...and `SELECT @@GLOBAL.foreign_key_checks` shows...

```
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.foreign_key_checks;
+-----------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.foreign_key_checks |
+-----------------------------+
|                           1 |
+-----------------------------+
```

With all the above settings, `mysql> INSERT INTO score (event_id,student_id,score) VALUES(9999,9999,0);` still succeeded.

It was not until I did `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1` that `INSERT` finally failed...

> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`sampdb`.`score`, CONSTRAINT `fk_event_id` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `grace_event` (`event_id`) ON UPDATE
>   CASCADE)

**Why did I have to `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1` when it (apparently) already was set to 1 by default?**  Does the default `@@GLOBAL.foreign_key_checks` setting not mean anything?  Is this a bug?

Comment: What returns `SELECT @@GLOBAL.foreign_key_checks, @@SESSION.foreign_key_checks;`?.

Comment: @wchiquito It returns `1` for each.

Comment: @wchiquito I'm guessing this means that `@@SESSION.foreign_key_checks` must have been set to `0` before I ran `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1`.  Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem:

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.25    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.foreign_key_checks, @@SESSION.foreign_key_checks;
+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.foreign_key_checks | @@SESSION.foreign_key_checks |
+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
|                           1 |                            1 |
+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `student`, `grace_event`, `score`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 3 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `student` (
    ->   `student_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `grace_event` (
    ->   `grace_event` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `score` (
    ->   `student_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    ->   `event_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    ->   `score` int(11) NOT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`,`student_id`),
    ->   KEY `student_id` (`student_id`),
    ->   CONSTRAINT `fk_event_id` FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`)
    ->     REFERENCES `grace_event` (`grace_event`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    ->   CONSTRAINT `fk_student_id` FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`)
    ->     REFERENCES `student` (`student_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `score`
    ->   (`event_id`, `student_id`, `score`)
    -> VALUES
    ->   (9999, 9999, 0);
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
                    constraint fails (`test`.`score`, CONSTRAINT
                    `fk_event_id` FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES
                    `grace_event` (`grace_event`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem after doing `SET @@GLOBAL.foreign_key_checks=1;`, `SET @@SESSION.foreign_key_checks=0`, and `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0` (duplicative of the latter).These must have been my settings when I posted my question, when I did not know about `@@GLOBAL` and `@@SESSION`.  Your earlier comment taught me that the reason the `INSERT` was successful was because `@@SESSION.foreign_key_checks` was `0`.  So,  even though `@@GLOBAL.foreign_key_checks` was `1`, `@@SESSION.foreign_key_checks` also needed to be `1`.  Thank you.